# Allow a WebView to view a 300x300px webpage in 1:1 pixels

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a square 300 *px* webpage.  Its dimensions are fixed and that's the way it has to be.  I created a 300 *px* WebView, and am trying to get the page to fit said WebvView precisely.  There should be no gaps - it should be 1:1 - pixel for pixel.

I've been trying various settings include playing with Meta *viewport* to no avail.  This is for Android 4.3, so SDK 18.  Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: The question provided the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229259/android-webview-is-it-acceptable-not-to-use-viewport-to-get-11-pixel-control

by simply not using a viewport tag at all, and using the following code in Java:

`WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();
settings.setSupportZoom(false);
browser.setInitialScale(100);`

Comment: Make an answer out of your comment and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question provided the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229259/android-webview-is-it-acceptable-not-to-use-viewport-to-get-11-pixel-control

> "by simply not using a viewport tag at all, and using the following code in Java:"

```
WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();  
settings.setSupportZoom(false);  
browser.setInitialScale(100);
```